# Automation using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a few clients that pay me to post ads on sites such as craigslist.com an backpage.com. Currently every hour or so I have a macro that runs and I manually do the captchas (which I'm fine with). But now I have some free time and I want to write a proper program to prevent stupid errors that can happen with macros (screen resize, miss clicks etc).

Part of my posting includes selecting images to upload. I know for security reasons javascript doesn't let you specify which file the user uploads, that part is decided on their own. I'm sure I could do it using NodeJS somehow since it would be local on my machine, but I don't even have the slightest idea how I would even approach this.

Any guidance or direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Look at PhantomJS + ZombieJS + CasperJS... They were popular some time ago, not sure what is the current "cutting edge"

Comment: I write scripts like this daily, I utilize cURL and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use nodeJS, you need to work hard, like
- get html content and parse it
- construct input that you want
- re-submit form, re-post data

the easier way is to use web browser automation like selenium to work end to end for you

more info: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar to Nodejs and JavaScript then I recommend you use [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/).

It is the current default end-to-end automation testing tool for AngularJs applications but I'm pretty sure it will solve your problem.

Instead of using AngularJs specific selectors (like element(by.model)) to "find" your html elements you will use regular css selectors like: $("div.top") returning an array of all divs with a css class named top, for exemple.

Protractor implements Selenium Web-driver protocol, that means that the scripts that you write will communicate with almost any automation ready browser like ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver or PhantomJsDriver (for a no GUI low fidelity but fast alternative).

Make sure you check the *getting started* section for a jump start.